# adding days to date in apex

Tags: sql, date, oracle-apex

I'm making a form where the user inputs their information and chooses a  reservation date. So, the user picks a reservation date, and based on that date, I want to generate an end date that is 4 days after the start date.

I also want to make it so that if their reservation starts on a Monday it ends on a Thursday or if it starts on a Thursday it ends on a Monday.

How can I get the end date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create your own PL/SQL stored procedure which will take in parameters the start date and the number of days to add.

Then your procedure will add the number of days and you will have a temp endDate.

Then, you will only have to check the day of the temp endDate, and if it is a weekend day, return the next Monday.

Apex allows you to have a dynamic action which can call a stored procedure and then update an item of your page.

Hope this helps.